# Deleting in C++

Tags: c++

```
struct item   
{ 
  unsigned int a, b, c;
};

item* items[10];    
delete items[5];    
items[5] = NULL;
```

The above code works

But the below method is not working

```
int * arr1[30];

delete (arr1+5);
```

I am a beginner, Please tell me why I am able to delete in case of structure pointer but not in case of int 
pointer

Answer (score 13):

You're seemingly misunderstanding what `delete` is for: it's purely and simply to release memory allocated by `new`, not to 'delete' elements of arrays.

So you might use it like this:

```
int *p = new int;
//...
delete p;
```

When you allocate arrays, you must instead use `delete[]`, like this:

```
int *q = new int[23];
//...
delete [] q;
```

But at no point should you try and `delete` something that hasn't been `new`'ed, or use the non-matching version of `delete`, e.g. `delete [] p;` or `delete q;` above.

If what you really want is some sort of 'array' from which you can remove elements, try this:

```
#include <vector>

struct item
{
    unsigned int a, b, c;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<item> items(10);
    items[5].a = 23;
    items.erase(items.begin() + 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's called 'fastest finger in the west' ;)

Answer (score 3):

Are you allocating heap memory anywhere? You are not doing so in the code above. You are lucky that the first delete does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `(arr1+5)` approach, you are passing the memory address of the array slot itself at index 5, not the `int*` that the slot contains.  To `delete` the `int*` that is contained in the slot at index 5, you have to dereference the pointer value, eg:

```
delete *(arr1+5);
```